# Error installing Codename One 4.4.0 as eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, codenameone

I tried installing the plugin for Codename One 4.4.0 in Eclipse (Luna upgraded to Photon) through the Eclipse Marketplace, but hadn't noticed I only had Java 8 JRE installed and not the JDK (hadn't used this installation for some time).

Codename One threw an error during installation, mentioning the missing JDK. I fixed the JDK dependency, but after that it looks like the plugin can't install correctly anymore. I tried again through the marketplace, and it now throws this error after a few seconds:

> An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
>   session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
>   Error reading signed content.
>   Exception in opening zip file: C:\Program Files\eclipse\features\CodenameOneFeature_4.4.0

I checked the directory "...\eclipse\features\" but it does not have a subdir "CodenameOneFeature_4.4.0\". I feel like something may have gone corrupt because of the previous failed install. Any ideas on how to keep the current Eclipse install but clean out the residues of that failed plugin install attempt?

Comment: _Help > About Eclipse IDE_, button _Installation Details_, tab _Installation History_, select date and click _Revert_.

Comment: Make sure your Eclipse.ini points at the JDK and not at the JRE https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestions! I ended up having to go for a clean install of Eclipse and now have Codename 5.0.0 running succesfully.